# While operator- overloading can i not return by reference?

Tags: c++, oop, reference

I know that in overloading of copy assignment operator we return object by reference to chain assignments together,but can't i do the same i.e return by reference while overloading operator- ?

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_cents;
public:
    Cents(int cents) { m_cents = cents; }
    friend Cents operator-( Cents &c1,  Cents &c2);// subtract Cents - Cents using a friend function
    int getCents() const { return m_cents; }
};

Cents &operator-( Cents &c1,  Cents &c2)
{
    c1.m_cents =  c1.m_cents - c2.m_cents;
    return c1;
}
```

Here i have overloaded using friend function. I have modified c1 object and returned it by reference. but i am getting errors , so can we do somthing like this ?

Comment: It is counter-intuitive for `operator -` to return an existing object.  It should return a brand new object.  Returning an existing object would make more sense for `operator -=`.  How would someone do `c = a - b;` if you're changing `a`?  Yes, you can change `a`, but be prepared for some harsh words from the person calling your function.

Comment: The result of `x - y` will almost always produce a whole new value that isn't currently represented by an object. That conflicts with returning a reference which is useful when you return a value that exists outside the context of the function.

Comment: Your definition of `operator-` doesn't match the declaration of the friend function.

Comment: Basically you're assigning your result back to `x`.  BTW this code won't compile.  Your definitions of `operator-` do not match.

Comment: First add the member function `Cents& operator-=(const Cents& rhs);` then make the free function `Cents operator-(const Cents& c1, const Cents& c2) { Cents rv(c1); rv -= c2; return rv; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that in overloading of copy assignment operator we return object by reference to chain assignments together,but can't i do the same i.e return by reference while overloading operator- ?

You can. But it definitely isn't better than creating a new object and returning the difference in that. After all, why change the value of the object passed?

Also note the difference in usage, you are having the `-` operator to be working as `x = x-y` (which is usually for `-=`) instead of `z = x-y`, where `z` is the new object where you would want to store the result of subtraction.

> Here i have overloaded using friend function. I have modified c1 object and returned it by reference. but i am getting errors , so can we do somthing like this ?

Your declaration of the friend function isn't a match for the operator overloaded definition, which is the reason for error.

Yes, you certainly can. However note that your operator overload pertains to `-=`, and not `-`.

Change the declaration within the class: (remove the `friend` keyword)

```cpp
Cents& operator-(const Cents& c1, const Cents &c2);
```

Corresponding definition of `-` overload, working as `-=`:

```cpp
Cents& operator-(const Cents& c1, const Cents& c2) 
{ 
    c1.m_cents -= c2.m_cents;
    return c1; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry but aren't you returning a reference to a stack allocated object  (ie diff) ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are actually performing the "-=" operation:

```
Cents& operator-=(const Cents& rhs)
{
  m_cents -= rhs.m_cents;
  return *this;
}
```

This is operator- :

```
Cents operator-(const Cents& c1, const Cents &c2)
{
  return Cents(c1.m_cents - c2.m_cents);
}
```